# Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator: when importing multiple packages

Tags: osgi, classnotfoundexception, apache-felix

I'm trying out OSGi samples from [apache felix](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/tutorials-examples-and-presentations/apache-felix-osgi-tutorial.html)

The first and second examples installed and started fine. But the third example where there is a dependency with osgi and previously installed service fails with class not found error.

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2 
Bundle-Name: French dictionary
Bundle-SymbolicName: fr-dict
Bundle-Description: A bundle that registers a French dictionary service
Bundle-Vendor: Apache Felix
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-Activator: tutorial.example2b.Activator
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, 
 tutorial.example2.service
```

Note: I have given a new line after the last line.

```
g! start file:/Users/johne/Desktop/bundle-dict-fr.jar                                                                                                                                                                    10:18:39
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle fr-dict [11].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2289)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2145)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.command.Basic.start(Basic.java:739)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:136)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:91)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:571)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:497)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:386)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.doCall(Pipe.java:417)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:229)
    at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.call(Pipe.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.defineClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2375)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2159)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1578)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getClassByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1404)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.createBundleActivator(Felix.java:4505)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2220)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator not found by fr-dict [11]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1610)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$200(BundleWiringImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 30 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/osgi/framework/BundleActivator
```

Here is lb output after that,

```
g! lb                                                                                                                                                                                                                    10:19:40
START LEVEL 1
   ID|State      |Level|Name
    0|Active     |    0|System Bundle (5.6.8)|5.6.8
    1|Active     |    1|jansi (1.16.0)|1.16.0
    2|Active     |    1|JLine Bundle (3.3.0)|3.3.0
    3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Bundle Repository (2.0.10)|2.0.10
    4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (1.0.2)|1.0.2
    5|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo JLine Shell (1.0.6)|1.0.6
    6|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (1.0.6)|1.0.6
    7|Active     |    1|Service listener example (1.0.0)|1.0.0
    8|Active     |    1|English dictionary (1.0.0)|1.0.0
   11|Resolved   |    1|French dictionary (1.0.0)|1.0.0
```

Comment: Does your MANIFEST.MF end with a newline?

Comment: Can you add the command line you use to startup?

Comment: `g! start file:/Users/johne/Desktop/bundle-dict-fr.jar `

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I got it fixed by rewriting the Import-Package line. Originally I copy-pasted the manifest file so there is propably some illegal character in it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a newline between the two imported packages:

```
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, 
tutorial.example2.service
```

Can you try to put both on the same line:

```
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework, tutorial.example2.service
```

I guess that in your current Manifest the Import-Package is ignored as the syntax is invalid. So your bundle resolves fine but does not import any packages. When the activator is then run it can not find any external classes.

Comment: If your imports are correct then this error should not occur. What does the Manifest in your jar contain now?

Comment: This is why I asked whether the MANIFEST.MF has a trailing newline. This is required in the manifest format and the last entry may not be correctly read if it is not there.

Comment: Yes I have a new line at the end. :-|. Note that this is the 3rd example in Felix documentation. The 1st and 2nd ran fine. And it is only in this example that we have multiple imports.

Comment: Indeed .. the tutorial shows exactly the Manifest you posted. I will try the example myself and report if I see the same problem. Btw. it is not advised to use felix without any further tools. There are two good alternative environments that get you up to speed faster. bndtools and Apache Karaf. I suggest to start with one of the tutorials there.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider thanks a ton. Let me know if you were able to reproduce the error. Meanwhile I'll have a look at Karaf